# The following nameservers failed to resolve to an IP address : ns2.exemple.fr

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

Actually I make a bind configuration master/slave on linux distro.

**info example** :

- domaine : exemple.fr
- master dns : 10.10.10.10
- slave dns : 10.10.10.11

My dns zone is well managed by the master. the zone transfer is done well to the slave, if I turn off the master, the slave takes over the configuration. However when I do a test via zone-master I get this error message:

```
The following nameservers failed to resolve to an IP address: ns2.exemple.fr. RCODE was REFUSED.
```

My two dedicated servers listen on tcp/udp 53 port.

**My resolv.conf on 2 machines** :

```
domain exemple.fr
search exemple.fr
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

**My master zone** :

```
$TTL 12H
@          IN              SOA            ns1.exemple.fr. postamaster.exemple.fr. (
           2020091701      ; Serial
           1H              ; Refresh
           30M             ; Retry
           4W              ; Expire
           3M              ; Minimum TTL
)
               IN              NS              ns1.exemple.fr.
               IN              NS              ns2.exemple.fr.
ns2            IN              NS              ns1.exemple.fr
; GLUE
           IN              A               10.10.10.10
           IN              A               10.10.10.11
; RECORD
ns1        IN              A               10.10.10.10
ns2        IN              A               10.10.10.11
```

Thank you for your help, feel free if you need any additional item regarding my setup

Comment: are you actually missing the final dot at the end of `ns2            IN              NS              ns1.exemple.fr` in your zone file or did this only occur during creation of the question?

Comment: Hi,  Sorry i'have forget delete this line before past on server fault. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check named.conf, probably you didn't configure **allow query** option on ns2.exemple.fr server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. My named.conf it's correct on my two servers.

Answer (score 0):

This record is rather strange, I'm not convinced it does what you think it does:

```
ns2            IN              NS              ns1.exemple.fr
```

What this means is that `ns2.exemple.fr.` is delegated to the nameserver `ns1.exemple.fr.example.fr.`, defining `ns2.exemple.fr` to be a zone of its own.
(Even if you wanted to do something like this, you probably should have a trailing dot rather than this strange `exemple.fr.example.fr.` name)

However, I don't see any obvious purpose for doing this, the question doesn't mention any desire to do such a thing, and it doesn't really seem reasonable.

Unless there actually is a real reason for delegating `ns2.exemple.fr.`, I would suggest just removing the associated records, leaving something like:

```
@          IN              SOA            ns1.exemple.fr. postamaster.exemple.fr. (
           2020091701      ; Serial
           1H              ; Refresh
           30M             ; Retry
           4W              ; Expire
           3M              ; Minimum TTL
)
               IN              NS              ns1.exemple.fr.
               IN              NS              ns2.exemple.fr.

; RECORD
ns1        IN              A               10.10.10.10
ns2        IN              A               10.10.10.11
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long time reply.

It's working now ! The zone master send me the error because it was not fully propagated. All the local tests were working.

Thank you for your reply.